how to approximate the eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix when the data have been standardized?
Context
I am working to develop a penalized regression framework that will scale up to analyzing high dimensional data with a certain correlation structure. Let $X$ represent an $n \times p$ matrix of data - rows are observations, columns are features. To adjust for the fact that features of $X$ are usually on different scales, I center and scale the columns of $X$ to obtain $\dot X$. The model I am studying requires the eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix $K = \frac{1}{p} \dot X \dot X^\top$, so I take $\text{eigen}(K) = USU^\top$ and use $U$ and $S$ in a subsequent transformation.
Present issue
Relevant to the present problem: I want to do cross-validation (CV) in order to choose a tuning parameter for my model (e.g., a tuning parameter $\lambda$ for a lasso model). In order to make sure the CV implementation represents every step of the modeling process, I need to standardize the training data $X^*$ in every fold. However, I want to avoid constructing $K^*$ and taking $\text{eigen}(K^*)$ in each fold, as this would be prohibitively expensive (computationally speaking). What I'd like to have is a relatively cheap way to approximate $U^*, S^*$, the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of the correlation matrix of the standardized training data.
Toy example
# before CV --------------------------
n <- 5
p <- 10

X <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)
std_X <- scale(X)
K <- tcrossprod(std_X)/p # correlation matrix 
eigen_K <- eigen(K)
U <- eigen_K$vectors
S <- diag(eigen_K$values)

# in CV -------------------------------
train <- sample(n, 3)  # indices of observations in training data 
train_X <- std_X[train,] # subset for folds 
std_train_X <- scale(train_X) # re-standardize to mirror full-model procedure

# true decomposition (what I need)
star_K <- tcrossprod(std_train_X)/ncol(train_X)
star_eigen_K <- eigen(star_K) # eigen = expensive!
star_U <- star_eigen_K$vectors 
star_S <- star_eigen_K$values

# CV subset 
train_U <- U[train,]
train_K <- tcrossprod(train_X)/ncol(train_X)

# ... but train_U and S do not represent a decomposition of star_K. 

Is there any way to avoid constructing & decomposing star_K in each fold? In particular, how (if at all) can star_U be approximated from the training data, the existing decomposition $U, S$, and the centering/scaling values used to standardize train_X into std_train_X?
